# How to populate canvas with images that has -webkit -transform and transform angle? below is my code:

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas, html5-canvas

```
   var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
   var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
   var img = document.getElementById("pan");
   img.setAttribute('crossOrigin','anonymous');
   ctx.drawImage(img,10,10);
   var img = document.getElementById("MyPix");
   img.setAttribute('crossOrigin','anonymous');
   ctx.drawImage(img,10,10);
```

As its context is 2d i cannot draw the image in canvas at any angle, webGl could be better solution but could not get any relevent example using webgl. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You can translate and rotate the context before drawing an image. To draw an image at a specific position, rotated by a specific angle, use this code:

```
ctx.save();
ctx.translate(10,10); // here the position for the image to be drawn
ctx.rotate(someAngle); // here your angle
ctx.drawImage(img,0,0); 
ctx.restore();
```

Note, that the above code will rotate your image by the left upper corner of the image. To rotate it by it's center use:

```
ctx.drawImage(img,-img.width*0.5,-img.height*0.5);
```

instead.

Comment: Thanks a lot.. that was really helpfull though its not considering the width and height i pass in ctx.drawImage(img,0,0);

Comment: If you want to rotate from center image then use: ctx.drawImage(img,-img.width/2,-img.height/2);

Comment: That's what I've already written in my answer. Just used *0.5 instead of /2.